# How exactly does one construct a covering space corresponding to a subgroup

Tags: algebraic-topology, general-topology

I'm trying to understand how to construct covers based on Hatcher and I'm using this question to understand it.

Let $B = B({a, b})$ be the wedge of circles.

$F(a, b)$ a free group on $\{a, b\}$.

Let $H = \langle b^2a, a^3b^{-1}, a^5 \rangle \leq F(a, b)$.

So I'm trying to construct a cover $p : \tilde{B} \to B$ such that $Im(p_∗) = H$.

The $p_∗ : \pi_1(B, \tilde{x_0}) \to \pi_1(B, x_0)$ is the homomorphism induced by p.

I think I'm getting a bit lost with this specific question. Can I ask to explain me the general process used maybe with a bit more simple example?

Comment: If you have the universal covering space $\widetilde{X}\to X$, it has an action by $\pi_1(X)$, hence an action by any subgroup $H\lt \pi_1(X)$. Take the quotient of $\widetilde{X}$ by $H$, and that will be the thing you want.